# Hide databound RadGrid rows

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, telerik, radgrid, objectdatasource

I have a telerik radgrid in my .aspx page name rgLowRise, and I have an ObjectDataSource as the DataSource set like `rgLowRise.DataSourceID = odsLowRise`. This works fine, but I want it not to show any records at first load, how can I do that? And I have to use `DataSourceID` and not `DataSource` due to some reasons.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the DataSourceID from the markup or your code behind (Page_Load) and set at a later stage, e.g. Button_Click or some other event

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rgLowRise.DataSourceID = odsLowRise; //until you click this button, the grid would display nothing
}
```